# Add container to array on button click

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, button, push

Okay, so originally, I had a program where when I clicked on the container, it added the entire container to an array, and then posted it in a sidebar.

Now I want it so when I click a button inside the div, it adds the entire container. Although I seem to have problems getting it working.

At the moment, it add the button to the array because I say `.push($(this))`

What would I use to add the entire individual div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the  [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) element.

```
favorites.push($(this).parent().clone());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPMNV/

Comment: Is there any way I could remove the button, once it is pushed to the array and posted on the sidebar?

Comment: @Christopher Your first assumption was correct, I upvoted your answer. Let's delete our comments.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the `parent` and then call remove on the `clone`

```
var clone = $(this).parent().clone();
$(clone.find("input")).remove();
favorites.push(clone);
$('.favorite').append(favorites);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPMNV/10/